# Body in free fall

Tags: gravity, relativity

I found an article on wikipedia saying:

> In the context of general relativity, where gravitation is reduced to a space-time curvature, a body in free fall has no force acting on it and moves along a geodesic

Does this mean that hypothetically, if I was in space and gravity was pulling me, I wouldn't feel it? It's easy to comprehend this if I think of Earth, but is it valid for any gravity? Even for massive objects like Jupiter or the sun? Even for black holes?

And how is this different from, lets say a train pulling me with the same gravitational acceleration?

Because of inertia, I would expect my internal organs to fail at higher gravitational accelerations.

Comment: Even for black holes, especially the big ones, you would have no idea that you had been pulled into a region that there was no way out of. Unless you resist gravity, by standing on the floor say, you will not feel it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that hypothetically, if I was in space and gravity was pulling me, I wouldn't feel it ?

You might consider an astronaut in space orbiting Earth.  That's free fall.

They experience no sensation of gravity, but if there was no gravity acting on them they'd shoot off into the void of space never to be seen again.  So that's free fall with gravity.

> It's easy to comprehend this if I think of Earth, but is it valid for any gravity? Even for massive objects like Jupiter or the sun? Even for black holes?
>
> And how is this different from, lets say a train pulling me with the same gravitational acceleration?

The [principle of equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) says (more or less) that there's no difference.

> Because of inertia, I would expect my internal organs to fail at higher gravitational accelerations.

You are "designed" for one-gee and exceeding the maker's guidelines voids your warranty.

Comment: Thanks you you reply. But in this case, regarding what Countt010 said, I would actually feel if a black hole was pulling me, right? Because there would surely be more than 1g there. So maybe I wouldn't feel gravity, but I would feel its effects, am I wrong?

Comment: I was not clear in my above comment. For large mass BH, you would not feel any force. Black holes are no different than any gravity source in that regard. But for a small black hole, because of tidal effects, your body  **would** be pulled into a cigar shaped mass. I don't know if you would have time to feel the effect of gravity in that situation, hopefully not.

Comment: Technically in a black hole if your feet was closer to it, you would feel your legs being pulled apart from your body. So yes you can feel the force. However, this happens extremely quickly.

Comment: @masterwarrior123 is referring to [Spagettification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification) which is one of my favorite words in all of Physics.